# What's the difference between MySQL `show processlist` and TiDB `show processlist`?

Tags: tidb

I'm familiar with MySQL `show processlist`. The `show processlist` statement in MySQL shows you which threads are running and can be useful when you get the "too many connections" error message and want to find out what is going on. Also, MySQL `show processlist` outputs the following columns: Id, User, Host, db, Command, Time, State and Info (See [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html)). So according to the above features that MySQL `show processlist` has, what's the difference between MySQL `show processlist` and TiDB `show processlist`?

Answer (score 0):

The display content of TiDB `show processlist` is almost the same as that of MySQL `show processlist`. TiDB `show processlist` does not display the system process ID. The ID that it displays is the current session ID. The differences between TiDB `show processlist` and MySQL `show processlist` are as follows:

- As TiDB is a distributed database, the `tidb-server` instance is a stateless engine for parsing and executing the SQL statements (for details, see [TiDB architecture](https://www.pingcap.com/docs/overview/#tidb-architecture)). `show processlist` displays the session list executed in the `tidb-server` instance that the user logs in to from the MySQL client, not the list of all the sessions running in the cluster. But MySQL is a standalone database and its `show processlist` displays all the SQL statements executed in MySQL.
- TiDB `show processlist` displays the estimated memory usage (unit: Byte) of the current session, which is not displayed in MySQL `show processlist`.